# jQuery with SharePoint 2010 best practice

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I was reading number of documents and still couldn't find a proper solution for this.
Here is my scenario:

We have an Intranet system with SharePoint 2010. It it having a main site and number of sub-sites within it. We have lot of pages across these sites and lot of custom web parts. Many of these pages and widgets (across main site and sub-sites) has to use jQuery.

My default master page: xxhttps://mycompany.com/_catalogs/masterpage/v4.master (or default.master)
My custom master page: xxhttps://mycompany.com/_catalogs/masterpage/myCustom.master

I have added below code to "myCustom.master" (to the place I have stated)

```
   <head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint"/>
<meta name="progid" content="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
<SharePoint:RobotsMetaTag runat="server"/>
<title id="onetidTitle"><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server"/></title>
<SharePoint:CssLink runat="server" DefaultUrl="/Style Library/MyStyle.css" Version="4"/>
<SharePoint:Theme runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:ULSClientConfig runat="server"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
var navBarHelpOverrideKey = "WSSEndUser";
</script>


<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="core.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:CustomJSUrl runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:SoapDiscoveryLink runat="server"/>

<script src="/Style%20Library/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Style%20Library/Scripts/jquery.timepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Style%20Library/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style%20Library/Scripts/jquery.timepicker.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style%20Library/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style%20Library/Scripts/site.css" />

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

I have copied all my jQuery, css and custom scripts to that folder: xxhttps://mycompany.com/Style Library/Scripts/
I want to use these scripts across the whole site/subsites and web parts (well I am good with web parts and main site pages where I am referring to my custom master page).
e.g: Here is one of my widgets pages

```
<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="_catalogs/masterpage/myCustom.master"    Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full"  %>
```

OK. Now the problem, to load jQuery within the pages of my sub-sites.

Here is one of my subsite pages in which I want to load jQuery: xxhttps://mycompany.com/howwedoit/teamA/SitePages/TeamADefaultPage.aspx

Here is the master page for the above page:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%> <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WikiEditPage" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full"       %>
```

So, "this masterpage" has no jQuery defined in it and jQuery is obviously not working.

Do I need to repeat the process for all these sub sites as I did for the main site (copy the jQuery folders and give reference links)? I don't want to do it but want to use the already existing libraries within the main site area.

How can I do it? And what's the best approach?

Comment: You need activate publishing feature on the root site , than go to the sub sites and you can specify to inherit the root-site master page.

Comment: Thanks Nish,

But the publishing feature is not available in SP Foundation we use here.
What's the best solution in that case?

Comment: To clarify, my main (and only - now) requirement is having one set of jQuery library files and use/refer it throughout the root site and all the sub-sites.
Please let me know the easiest/best way.